# Ionic slide box with button bar

Tags: angularjs, slideshow, ionic-framework, slide

I have an ionic slide box with 4 slides. You can switch between slides by clicking buttons on the bottom of the screen. How do I add class 'active' (using AngularJS) to the button when it's corresponding slide is active?

For example, if the second slide is active I want second button to have class 'active'. When you move to third slide (either by clicking third button or by sliding the screen), class 'active' is removed from second button and added to third button.

Here is my code:

**menu.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Menu">

    <ion-content class="padding">

        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="activateTabs($index)">

            <ion-slide>
                <h1> Slide 1 </h1>
            </ion-slide>

            <ion-slide>
                <h1> Slide 2 </h1>
            </ion-slide>

            <ion-slide>
                <h1> Slide 3 </h1>
            </ion-slide>

            <ion-slide>
                <h1> Slide 4 </h1>
            </ion-slide>

        </ion-slide-box>

    </ion-content>

    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-stable" ng-click="slide(0)">1</a>
        <a class="button button-stable" ng-click="slide(1)">2</a>
        <a class="button button-stable" ng-click="slide(2)">3</a>
        <a class="button button-stable" ng-click="slide(3)">4</a>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

**MenuCtrl.js**

```
myApp

.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate){

    $scope.slide = function(to) {
        $scope.current = to;
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(to);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining your buttons in the controller, so you can use `$index` to conditionally add a class to an object with `ng-class`.

Your code would look like this.

**HTML**

Add `ng-repeat` & `ng-class` in your html.

When you click on a button, $scope.current will be the same as the $index of that specific button button. Therefore `ng-class` will only add the class `active` to the clicked button.

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a ng-repeat="button in buttons"
       ng-class="{'active': $index === current}"
       ng-click="slide($index)"
       class="button button-stable">{{ button.name }}</a>
</div>
```

**Controller**

Define your buttons with `$scope.buttons`
inside your controller.

```
myApp

.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate){

    $scope.buttons = [
        { name: '1' },
        { name: '2' },
        { name: '3' },
        { name: '4' }
    ];

    $scope.slide = function(to) {
        $scope.current = to;
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(to);
    }

});
```

**CSS**

Now you need to define a class `.active` in your css somewhere, since we declared it in your html with the `ng-class` directive ('active').

```
ng-class="{'active': $index === current}"
```

Comment: this works perfectly on click but the class does not change when you scroll between screens. any tips on that? Also each button should have a different icon. Can I somehow add icons from controller? - @mhx

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question about that, since it's another 'case'.
There's an angular library which can do this:
https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll#events

I haven't used it yet, good luck!